# How to say "to receive an email" in Japanese?

Tags: words

How to say "to receive an email" in Japanese?
For example, in sentences such as "Did you receive my email?" or "I did not receive your email."

In my dictionary, I can find the words 受ける and 受け取る as "receive", but without examples corresponding to "receive an email".

[Here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/96277/how-to-say-reply-to-an-email-in-japanese), the verb もらう is used (この前**もらった**メールに返信するの忘れてた).

So, is it もらう that can be used systematically? Are there other verbs?

Comment: “Receive to an email” is not standard English — if you could clarify what you think it means, it would help us work out what it should correspond to.

Comment: @jogloran It was a typo, I corrected it, thank you for pointing it out

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://ja.hinative.com/questions/6421

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following words to express "to receive an email" in Japanese.

1. メールを**受け取る**
2. メールが**くる**
3. メールが**とどく**
4. メールを**もらう**

1 is often used in a bit more formal situations.
2 is mostly used in casual situations. You don't use in formal situations.

4 contains a slightly different nuance.

1-3 indicates that you got the email in your inbox, but the other person can't necessarily tell weather if you have read the email or not.

On the other hand, if you use「もらう」, it sounds more like you have read the email. That's the reason why it's used 「この前もらったメールに返信するの忘れてた。」. You have received and read it, but you forgot to reply.

Example sentences are below:

### "Did you receive my email?"

(All are in casual situations, asking your friends)

> 会社からメールきた？
>
> Did you receive the email from work?

> 昨日メール送ったんだけど、とどいた？
>
> I sent you an email yesterday, did you receive it?

> ごめんごめん、先週メールくれたよね。返事するの忘れてた。
>
> Oh sorry sorry, you gave me an email (I receive your email) last week hey. I forgot to reply.

### "I did not receive your email."

(A bit in formal situation)

> メールを受け取っていないのですが。
>
> I haven't received the email.

(The rest of the sentences are in casual situations)

> 採用のメールこなかった。
>
> I didn't receive a job offer email.

> A: 昨日送ったメール読んだ？
>
> Did you read the email I sent you yesterday?
>
> B: え？メールきてないよ？（とどいてないよ？）
>
> What? I didn't get the email?

### Note

メールを受ける is not really used.

Comment: Why the particles が, を, etc. are not added in the examples (ex. 昨日送ったメール読んだ; 先週メールくれたよね)? Particles are not mandatory?

Comment: @starckman Particles are often omitted in Japanese casual expressions. To put it simply, we don't omit particles that don't make sense or change the meaning without it.

Comment: Understood, ありがとうございます

Comment: どういたしまして！これからも日本語の勉強がんばってください＾＾